Is my question about free will and law on-topic?
Earlier I posted a question about free will. By the time I got around to checking my stackexchange account, my question had been migrated to Law SE, put on hold there, and now I can’t even comment. 
I chose Psychology & Neuroscience SE for my question because I thought I would get the best answer here. I almost submitted the question to Law SE, then considered Philosophy SE, but I eventually decided that Psychology would have the right people to answer my question because it requires someone who has denied free will and actually thought about the implications.
I don’t mind to edit some of the terms and add sources, but I would like to know if the question can be moved back to Psychology so I can edit it accordingly. Thanks!

Your question is one that borders several disciplines, and those questions may take a while to find their home. In this case I migrated as the question is:

What justice and legislative system reforms have been proposed that account for the absence of free will?

So your asking about matters of law, and afaik you are looking for an answer like: 'These reforms have been put in place: A)... B)...'
If your question was, e.g.., 'What are the reasons and underlying data that have led to the idea of an absence of free will in criminals?', that would've been better on-topic here.
I have transferred it now for a second time to politics, in answer to the suggestions made over at Law. If bounced over at Politics, I would propose go to Philosophy, but personally I don't think it's a philosophical question.
Edit
It has been accepted over at Politics. 

Thanks for the explanation. I’ll wait and see how it plays out at Politics SE. I thought Psychology SE would be a good place, because if I’m not mistaken, don’t psychologists evaluate “insanity” cases and then offer treatment options? So I’m really asking what treatment options have been considered if every criminal/lawbreaker is “insane/mentally challenged”? I know treatment for addicts, rather than useless punishment, has been proposed- and that seems like a psychology subject.

@anonymouswho - I understand where you're coming from. Let us see what happens next over at Politics and otherwise we'll leave it here I guess. I'm just pretty sure your question won't be answered here - we're pretty much a scientific site and we like references and sorts. This question is different imo. Further, the question scope is pretty broad, as it may, and likely will differ from country to country. Where should one start to answer this question?
